# Prevent abstract implementation from overriding certain method

Tags: java, oop

I have an interface called `Worker` which I want to expose so that the end-user can simply call:

```
Worker w = WorkerFactory.createInstance();
w.mainBit();
```

How can I prevent classes which extend my `AbstractWorker` class from providing *their own* implementation of the `mainBit` method?

This is the structure I have so far:

```
interface Worker {
    void mainBit();
}

class WorkerFactory {
    public static Worker createInstance() {
        return new WorkerImpl();
    }
}

abstract class AbstractWorker implements Worker {
    @Override
    public void mainBit() {
        this.doThing1();
        this.doThing2();
    }

    public abstract void doThing1();
    public abstract void doThing2();
}

class WorkerImpl extends AbstractWorker {
    @Override
    public void doThing1() {

    }

    @Override
    public void doThing2() {

    }

    @Override
    public void mainBit() {
        // I don't want classes to override this functionality
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by making the method `final`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the final keyword.

```
public final void mainbit ()
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Mark the method as `final`, which prevents overriding:

```
public final void mainBit()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to always use the AbstractWorker's mainBit, make it final in this class. This way, the subclasses won't override it.

Answer (score 1):

Mark it `final` inside you abstract class (in Java). No other subclass will be allowed to override it.